# Unable to get <systemPropertyVariables> variable values from pom

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, maven, pom.xml

Hi I am working on a java maven project in which I have to define some variables in the pom.xml file.

I have defined a variable as follows in my pom.xml file.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
        <configuration>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*Test*.java</include>
                <include>**/*Tests*.java</include>
                <include>**/Test*.java</include>
            </includes>
            <systemPropertyVariables>
                <my.value>NOTNULL</my.value>
            </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

To try accessing the `my.value` variable, I am using the following piece of Java code.

```
    String testdata = System.getProperty("my.value");
    System.out.println(testdata);
```

But the console output always shows me `null` even when I set the value of the variable.

Can anyone point out what is wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT : I have also tried declaring the `systemPropertyVariables` under the `maven-failsafe-plugin` but with no change.

**NOTE**: When I try to convert the testdata line of code as follows,

```
   String testdata = System.getProperty("my.value").toString();
```

I get a NullPointer Exception at the above line.

Edit: Sorry for posting this as an answer earlier..

I am running it as JUnit test using the plugin ... /plugin code you provided but here is my console output..

```
21 Oct 2014 12:36:56,973 main                                     INFO  s.MyClass                  - Default Implicit timeout set in Driver to: 100  
21 Oct 2014 12:36:56,973 main                                     INFO  s.MyClass                  - Default URL for server is set to: http://localhost:8080
 ---- null
```

The URL is what i am trying to retrieve from the pom.xml file and the condition i have written is that

if the value in the variable is empty of starts with ${ then return localhost:8080 else return the url.

So if you could point me to something wrong here

Comment: I have never heard of accessing variables from you pom.xml.  Maven is a build System and has nothing to do with running your code. Unless you are talking about Tests that are fired from Maven?

Comment: @ScaryWombat i am running JUnit tests for mobile automation.

Answer (score 5):

Works for me with `maven-3.2.3` on `Windows` with `JDK 1.6.0_67`

Created a project with `maven-archetype-quickstart`...

Added relevant pom lines... combining [surefire example](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html) with specific lines in the question above.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
    <configuration>
      <systemPropertyVariables>
        <my.value>NOTNULL</my.value>
        <buildDirectory>${project.build.directory}</buildDirectory>
      </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Relevant lines in AppTest.java

```
/**
 * Rigourous Test :-)
 */
public void testApp()
{
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("my.value"));
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("buildDirectory"));
    assertTrue( true );
}
```

Relevant output from `mvn test`

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.mycompany.app.AppTest
NOTNULL
C:\Users\raghu\Documents\GitHub\mvn-examples\test-properties\target
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 sec - in c
om.mycompany.app.AppTest
```

[Here](https://github.com/maruhgar/mvn-examples/tree/master/test-properties) is the project in github.

Comment: do i have to specify the project.build.directory anywhere and if yes what should be its value ?

Comment: i am running JUnit tests for mobile webpae automation using appium so when i run my project as Maven test, it throws an error when i am instantiating my AppiumDriver.
Any idea what to do ?

Comment: `buildDirectory` is just an example value. You can see `pom` snippet above to see how the value is set for it.

Answer (score 3):

You stumbled here on a [known limitation](https://www.eclipse.org//lists/m2e-users/msg03823.html) of the Eclipse IDE (the question is tagged with `eclipse`).

While the `mvn test` command outside of Eclipse would work similar to the "Maven test" run configuration in the Eclipse IDE, the "JUnit Test" run configuration is a completely different part of Eclipse IDE running the test code. And JUnit Eclipse integration (at least up to JUnit version 4 which I am running) does not have an integration with the M2Eclipse plugin (the one bringing the Maven features inside Eclipse). Hence JUnit features in Eclipse are not aware of the Maven features and viceversa. Therefore:

- you cannot see the `Maven test` results in the JUnit test result view
- JUnit will not read your Maven profile or any other Maven-specific configuration (like the `systemPropertyVariables` surefire configuration)

In @Raghuram's answer, he made it work because he is running `mvn test` (outside Eclipse) or "Maven test" (inside Eclipse). If he would also run the test code using the JUnit Eclipse integration, he would also get the `null` value for those properties.

What solutions do you have:

- as pointed by @Raghuram's answer, use Maven to run the tests with the following disadvantage:

  - you cannot easily run one single test or a package of tests from the ui; you would have to edit that Maven run configuration and provide test filtering argument there. I guess you would be faster then using the terminal outside Eclipse
  - you will not see the "Maven test" results in the JUnit view (which itself has a few handy features)
- use another IDE (like InteliJ IDEA) with the following disadvantages:

  - it is not free
  - learning a new IDE
- use the terminal outside Eclipse to run the tests with the following disadvantages:

  - you will miss you IDE features that speed up troubleshooting
  - you cannot debug like you are used to in your IDE

Comment: That's what I suspected...  however, the IntelliJ Community edition is open source and free...

Answer (score -4):

@Raghuram Thanks for helping .

I got the way to work around this problem.

In my java file, in the @Before annotation, i am setting the value of the variable as follows

```
 System.setProperty("my.value","this value");
```

And now it works just fine.

Cheers.

**Note : Guys i am sorry for posting another question as an answer.. :(**